# Javascript "this.socket.of..." what does this line of code mean/do

Tags: javascript, sockets

I have developed this node js snake game and as im a beginner i've been copying and pasting bits of code from what other people have done and now im going back through my project and commenting and figuring out what every line of code does. I came across these 2 lines of code that look similar but if i take one out, the game still functions as normal and I am worried that I am taking out something important behind the scenes

i dont think the listener is relevant but just in case. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your socket seems to implement an event emitter. That means it implements a method for emitting events (which you can call from wherever, whenever something happens) and a method for registering event listeners.

Have a look at the nodejs EventEmitter API: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

The server seems to have an event emitter within as well, "server.em".

I am guessing your code emits two events when the player connects, one from the socket event emitter (first line) and a second one from the "global" server event emitter. I imagine this is the intended purpose. Since I don't have more info about what you did there, I can't tell you why it's like that :)

Removing the first line seems to not do anything because you don't have an event listener registered on the socket. Or, if you do, it does not do anything visible.

Try to add an event listener:

```
server.socket.of("/snake").addListener("server.spawnSnake", function(playerId) {
    console.log("Socket: snake spawn for player "+playerId);
}
```

And you will see the message appearing only if you keep the first line.

Comment: so since i dont have a listener for the first line, should i just delete it? since it works fine without it

Comment: Yeah, you can delete it for now and maybe you'll add it again later if you need it. If you don't have such a listener for it, it is for sure not needed.